# equation label on newline - unexpected behaviour

Tags: line-breaking, align

I'm having an issue with the align function where the number label of the last equation is shown on the line below the last equation/line. I would like this to be on the same line.

The latex code I am using is shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\min \sum_{t = 1}^{n^{T}} \sum_{i = 1}^{n^{I}} F(g_{i,t}) - F(l_{i,t})   \label{O1}\\
s.t.\ to \nonumber\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} g_{i,t}d^{i1}_{mn} + \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} l_{i,t}d^{1i}_{mn} + \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}}(u_{i,t}^{+} + u_{i,t}^{-})d^{1i}_{mn} \leq h_{mn} & \nonumber \\ \quad \forall mn,t \quad dual:\mu_{mn,t} & \label{O2}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} l_{i,t} + \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} (u_{i,t}^{+} + u_{i,t}^{-}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} g_{i,t} = 0 \quad \forall t \quad dual:\lambda_{t} \label{O3}\\
\underline{g}_{i,t} \leq g_{i,t} \leq \bar{g}_{i,t} \quad \forall i,t \quad \quad dual:\eta^{-}_{i,t},\eta^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O4}\\
\underline{l}_{i,t} \leq l_{i,t} \leq \bar{l}_{i,t} \quad \forall i,t \quad dual:\alpha^{-}_{i,t},\alpha^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O5}\\
0 \leq u_{i,t}^{+} \leq \bar{q}_{i}^{pc} \quad \forall i,t \quad dual:\chi^{0,+}_{i,t},\chi^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O6}\\
-\bar{q}_{i}^{pc} \leq u_{i,t}^{-} \leq 0 \quad \forall i,t \quad dual:\chi^{-}_{i,t},\chi^{0,-}_{i,t}
\label{O7}\\
0 \leq e_{i,t} \leq \bar{q}_{i}^{ec} \quad \forall i,t \quad dual:\gamma^{-}_{i,t},\gamma^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O8}\\
e_{i,t+1} = \tau_{i,t}e_{i,t} + \upsilon_{i,t}^{+}u_{i,t}^{+} + \upsilon_{i,t}^{-}u_{i,t}^{-}\quad \forall i,t \quad dual:\sigma_{i,t}
\label{O9}\\
hello \quad &
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: amsmath just moves the label down (or up) if there is no room on the same line.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be any room on that last line? There is plenty of room. In fact the issue doesn't show when I remove the last eqn/line.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you've encountered -- the fact that `amsmath` moves the equation number down a bit if there's not enough space on a line for both the formula and the equation number -- is merely a symptom of a much more severe issue: You are using an `align` environment, but you are not using it correctly.

It's not clear to me what the *best* layout may be for the formulas at hand. For sure, though, left-aligning all material, by prefixing `&` alignment points at the start of each line would seem preferable to the current layout.

Separately, I would also render the "dual:" bits in text mode rather than in math mode, and I would use an `\intertext` directive  to typeset the "subject to" line that follows the very first line. Finally, I must confess I don't understand the meaning or content of the final line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock

\begin{align}
&\min \sum_{t = 1}^{n^{T}} \sum_{i = 1}^{n^{I}} F(g_{i,t}) - F(l_{i,t})   \label{O1}\\
\intertext{subject to}
&\sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} g_{i,t}d^{i1}_{mn} + \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} l_{i,t}d^{1i}_{mn} + \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}}(u_{i,t}^{+} + u_{i,t}^{-})d^{1i}_{mn} \leq h_{mn}  \nonumber \\ 
&\qquad \forall mn,t \quad \text{dual: }\mu_{mn,t}  \label{O2}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} l_{i,t} + \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} (u_{i,t}^{+} + u_{i,t}^{-}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n^{I}} g_{i,t} = 0 \quad \forall t \quad \text{dual: }\lambda_{t} \label{O3}\\
&{\underline{g}}_{i,t} \leq g_{i,t} \leq \bar{g}_{i,t} \quad \forall i,t \quad \quad \text{dual: }\eta^{-}_{i,t},\eta^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O4}\\
&{\underline{l}}_{i,t} \leq l_{i,t} \leq \bar{l}_{i,t} \quad \forall i,t \quad \text{dual: }\alpha^{-}_{i,t},\alpha^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O5}\\
&0 \leq u_{i,t}^{+} \leq \bar{q}_{i}^{pc} \quad \forall i,t \quad \text{dual: }\chi^{0,+}_{i,t},\chi^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O6}\\
&{-}\bar{q}_{i}^{pc} \leq u_{i,t}^{-} \leq 0 \quad \forall i,t \quad \text{dual: }\chi^{-}_{i,t},\chi^{0,-}_{i,t}
\label{O7}\\
&0 \leq e_{i,t} \leq \bar{q}_{i}^{ec} \quad \forall i,t \quad \text{dual: }\gamma^{-}_{i,t},\gamma^{+}_{i,t}
\label{O8}\\
&e_{i,t+1} = \tau_{i,t}e_{i,t} + \upsilon_{i,t}^{+}u_{i,t}^{+} + \upsilon_{i,t}^{-}u_{i,t}^{-}\quad \forall i,t \quad \text{dual: }\sigma_{i,t}
\label{O9}\\
&hello \quad(\text{are you sure?)}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted everything aligned to the right? The issue seems to creep up only when I align right, which doesn't manifest when I removed the last equation.

Comment: @sayan - Can you give me a (good) use case for aligning all formuals to the right (aka "the raggedleft look")? IMNSHO, raggedleft is a singularly dubious choice for a stack of formulas.

Comment: I don't think i will be able to convince why aligning the formulas to the right is preferable or useful and I may have to resort to left aligning. But, I would like to know the reason why right aligning doesn't work for this specific case.